# How do I properly chain tasks in C#?

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, task

I've been trying to run the first task to create a .NET project then pass the directory to the second task to add the required packages to the project, but when I try chaining the tasks together it only runs the first one and doesn't do anything after it's completed.

```
private Process? process;

public async Task DotnetCreate(string projectDirectory, string projectName)
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CreateDotnetProject(projectDirectory, projectName))
        .ContinueWith((t1) => AddDotnetPackages(newPath),
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}

public async Task CreateDotnetProject(string projectDirectory, string projectName)
{
    process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = {
            FileName = "dotnet",
            Arguments = $"new console --name {projectName}",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,

            WorkingDirectory = projectDirectory
        }
    };
    process.Start();
    process.Dispose();
    newPath = Path.Combine(projectDirectory, projectName);
    await AddDotnetPackages(newPath);
    // await Task.Delay(1000);
}

public async Task AddDotnetPackages(string projectDirectory)
{
    process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = {
            FileName = "dotnet",
            Arguments = $"add package DSharpPlus --version 4.2.0",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            WorkingDirectory = projectDirectory
        }
    };

    process.Start();
    //await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Why use `ContinueWith` when you can just call `AddDotnetPackages(newPath);` on the next line (since you're awaiting the task)?

Comment: please share the output from debugger or result of the problem. Also, in the future, please put description of your problem before the code

Comment: I tried it with those corrections and it didn't work, also there are no errors in the output it just runs then goes back to normal without running AddDotnetPackage

Answer (score 2):

> How do I properly chain tasks in c#

With `await`:

```
public async Task DotnetCreate(string projectDirectory, string projectName)
{
  await CreateDotnetProject(projectDirectory, projectName);
  await AddDotnetPackages(newPath);
}
```

Note that, as with most code, it's cleaner if you pass and return parameters, rather than setting them as side effects:

```
public async Task DotnetCreate(string projectDirectory, string projectName)
{
  var newPath = await CreateDotnetProject(projectDirectory, projectName);
  await AddDotnetPackages(newPath);
}

public async Task<string> CreateDotnetProject(string projectDirectory, string projectName)
{
  ...
  return Path.Combine(projectDirectory, projectName);
}
```

Comment: It still only goes through with the first task

Comment: @Mayowa.Ak: I'm not sure I understand. If the first throws an exception then the second won't run. Otherwise it will run once the first completes.